# Cross application query is not supported for more than 10 applications/resources

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Error code 
properties.source.authorizedResources has 18 applications/resources listed. Cross application query is not supported for more than 10 applications/resources

Am trying to create and alert for exceptions accross all application insights but it fails during creating with above error.

Am using more than 10 `app('name')` commands to union accross different application insights.

I cannot create this alert on loganalytics target (custom search query) because it give query parse error . hence i had to chose and existing application insight target resource to create this alert. When i choose any existing application insight resource as target then it parses query successfully but when i click create alert it fails with above error.

```
app('app1').exceptions 
union app('app2').exceptions 
union ..... upto 15 apps 
|project problemId]
```

Query:

1. why my query fails to parse when target is loganalytics
2. when in use appinsight as target then how can i remove 10 app restriction.

Comment: for log analytics is the keyword `workspace` instead of `app`? forwarded this on to the team that owns cross app queries for the rest of it.

Answer (score 0):

The response I got from the team that owns alerts:

> Currently, support for cross application queries is in preview and we have restricted it to 10 apps in preview.

they are looking at how people use it and investigating upping the limit.  but for now, yes, the limit inside alerts is 10 resources.

Here's a link to the docs that has this info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitor-alerts-unified-log#log-search-alert-rule---definition-and-types

> **Important**
>
> Suppport of cross application query for Application Insights is in preview - the functionality limited to use with 2 or more apps and user experience is subject to change. Usage of cross workspace query and cross-resource query for Log Analytics is currently not supported in Azure alerts.